# How can I trigger an event once Lottie animation reaches a certain frame?

Tags: javascript, animation, lottie, bodymovin

Using Lottie/BodyMoving, how can I trigger an event once the Lottie animation reaches a certain frame.

For example: Once anim1 reaches a certain frame, I want anim2 to play.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `enterFrame` event

```js
  const anim = lottie.loadAnimation({ ...options, path: 'URL_TO_JSON' });
anim.addEventListener('enterFrame', () => {
  console.log('enterFrame', anim.currentFrame);
  if(anim.currentFrame == 55)
  {
  //stop and play 2nd one
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bodymovin/5.5.9/lottie.js"></script>
 <div style="width:1067px;height:600px"  class="lottie" data-animation-path="animation/" data-anim-loop="true" data-name="ninja"></div>
```